# ORACLE SQL Method Produces Warning

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I'm having trouble getting the following member method to compile (count_single_buses). Would appreciate any advice on what might be wrong syntactically with my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BodyModel2_Type AS OBJECT(
ModelID INTEGER,
ModelName VARCHAR2(45),
FloorType VARCHAR2(45),
Manufacturer VARCHAR2(45),
Length NUMBER(8,2),
Width NUMBER(8,2),
NoOfAxles INTEGER,
MEMBER FUNCTION count_single_buses(ModelID INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER);
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BodyModel2_Type AS
MEMBER FUNCTION count_single_buses(ModelID INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER IS
N INTEGER;
BEGIN
    N := (SELECT COUNT(BODYMODELREF) FROM SINGLEDECKBUS_TABLE S 
          WHERE S.BODYMODELREF = ModelID);
    RETURN N;
END count_single_buses;
END;
```

--EDIT--

Thanks to @Ravi, I managed to solve the issue my correcting my SQL syntax and setting the resultset to a NUMBER, instead of INTEGER.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BodyModel_Type AS
MEMBER FUNCTION count_single_buses(thisModelID INTEGER) RETURN NUMBER IS
NUM NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(S.BODYMODELREF) INTO NUM FROM SINGLEDECKBUS_TABLE S WHERE S.BODYMODELREF.MODELID = thisModelID;
    RETURN NUM;
END count_single_buses;
END;
/
```

Still not sure why @Ravi's exact code still produced the warning, and thought that resultset when returning a count value could go into an integer. At any rate, the code works now. Thanks all.

Comment: Care to share that warning or error message with us?

Comment: Running in Oracle SQL Developer, the script output is:

`TYPE BODY BodyModel2Type compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning`

Comment: Does that forward slash under the word member belong there?

Comment: Word of warning (from me, not from Oracle) - do not use Object Relational features in tables, you'll probably end up in pain. Objects/Types are cool in PL/SQL but don't try to store them.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I was taught when creating types to end with the forward slash. 
[found this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1622/why-does-sqlplus-need-a-slash-after-create-type)

Comment: @user3746803 You should accept Ravi's answer (by clicking the checkmark) if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, thanks for the directions. Done and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BodyModel2_Type` Type definition looks okay. However, the body definition is syntactically incorrect.

You cannot define a SQL statement directly to a variable, thus making this statement wrong.

```
N := (SELECT COUNT(BODYMODELREF) FROM SINGLEDECKBUS_TABLE S 
          WHERE S.BODYMODELREF = ModelID);
```

You will have to use `Select... into` statement in order to assign the result set of your SQL query into a variable. So, the right syntax should look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(BODYMODELREF) FROM SINGLEDECKBUS_TABLE S  INTO N
              WHERE S.BODYMODELREF = ModelID
```

AFAIK you don't have `END` the `Type` followed by the `Type name` like this
 `END count_single_buses`.
 It'll produce an error. So, overall your Type body specification should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BodyModel2_Type AS
MEMBER FUNCTION count_single_buses(ModelID INTEGER) RETURN NUMBER IS
N NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(BODYMODELREF) FROM SINGLEDECKBUS_TABLE S INTO N
          WHERE S.BODYMODELREF = ModelID;
    RETURN (N);
END;
END;
/
```

I'm writing this off without any live environment available right now so please let me know if you come across any error in the above code.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've got my code working based on what you've described, though your exact code still produced the same warning. I modified the return to NUMBER instead of INTEGER, and now it works. 

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BodyModel_Type AS
 MEMBER FUNCTION count_single_buses(thisModelID INTEGER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    NUM NUMBER;
 BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(S.BODYMODELREF) INTO NUM FROM SINGLEDECKBUS_TABLE S WHERE S.BODYMODELREF.MODELID = thisModelID;
  RETURN NUM;
 END count_single_buses;
END;
/`

I would've thought that sql result set would have worked with an integer though?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When you're working on Java it's hard to keep an eye on data types declaration of other languages. Oracle use standard `number` as data type for all integer values which is why your code wasn't working earlier. Edited my post. Please accept the answer if you found it useful.